# agregar una columna a un csv que exporto en php

Tags: javascript, php

estoy tratando de buscar mi csv para agregar una columna extra que me falta pero el codigo php es del año 2010 entonces hay varias cosas que no entiendo bien aqui pongo el ejemplo de la tabla que necesito se exporte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en mi csv se exporta pero falta la columna  completed

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

se supone que este es mi codigo original

```
<?php
   
    foreach($billsec as $idx=>$key) {
        echo "<tbody>\n";
            if(count($departments)>1) {

                $group_bill_print = seconds2minutes($group_bill[$idx]);
      
                if($group_calls[$idx]>0) {
                    $avg_ring_group = $group_ring[$idx] / $group_calls[$idx];
                } else {
                    $avg_ring_group = 0;
                }

                $avg_ring_group = number_format($avg_ring_group,0);

                $texto  = "<table width=400 border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>";
                $texto .= "<caption>".$rep_title."</caption>";
                $texto .= "<tbody>";
                $texto .= "<tr class=\'section\'>";
                $texto .= "<td>Account Code:";
                $texto .= "<td>$idx</td>";
                $texto .= "</tr>";
                $texto .= "<tr>";
                $texto .= "  <td>"._('No Calls').":</td>";
                $texto .= "  <td>".$group_calls[$idx]." "._('calls')."</td>";
                $texto .= "</tr>";
                $texto .= "<tr>";
                $texto .= "  <td>"._('Total Time').":</td>";
                $texto .= "  <td>$group_bill_print</td>";
                $texto .= "</tr>";
                $texto .= "<tr>";
                $texto .= "  <td>"._('Avg Ringtime').":</td>";
                $texto .= "  <td>$avg_ring_group "._('secs')." </td>";
                $texto .= "</tr>";
                $texto .= "</tbody>";
                $texto .= "</table>";
                echo "<tr ><td colspan=10 style='text-align: left;' bgcolor='#cc9900'><a style='color: black;' href='javascript:void();' class='info'>";
                echo "<span>"._('account_code')."</span> $idx </a></td></tr>\n";

           }

            $data_pdf   = Array();
            $header_pdf = Array (
                               _('User'),
                               _('Calls'),
                               _('Missed'),
                               _('Percent'),
                               _('Bill secs'),
                               _('Percent'),
                               _('Avg. Calltime'),
                               _('Ring Time'),
                               _('Avg. Ring')
            );
            $width_pdf=array(40,15,15,15,25,20,25,25,25);
            $title_pdf=$rep_title;

           $contador=0;
           $query1="";
           $query2="";
           $query3="";

           foreach($key as $chan=>$val) {

                $contavar = $contador +1;
                $cual = $contador % 2;
                if($cual>0) { $odd = " class='odd' "; } else { $odd = ""; }

                $nomuser=$canals[$chan];
                $nomissed = $number_calls[$idx][$chan] - $missed[$idx][$chan];
                $yesmissed   = $missed[$idx][$chan];
                $query1 .= "valA$contavar=$nomissed&valB$contavar=$yesmissed&var$contavar=$nomuser&";
                $query2 .= "val$contavar=".$val."&var$contavar=$nomuser&";
                $query3 .= "valA$contavar=".$number_calls[$idx][$chan]."&valB$contavar=".$number_in_calls[$idx][$chan]."&var$contavar=$nomuser&";

                $ring_time = $duration[$idx][$chan]-$val;

                if($number_calls[$idx][$chan]>0) {
                    $avg_ring_time = $ring_time / $number_calls[$idx][$chan];
                    if($nomissed>0) {
                        $avg_duration  = $val / $nomissed;
                    } else {
                        $avg_duration = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    $avg_duration  = 0;
                    $avg_ring_time = 0;
                }
                $avg_duration = number_format($avg_duration,0);
                $avg_duration_print = seconds2minutes($avg_duration);
                $avg_ring_time = number_format($avg_ring_time,2);
                $time_print = seconds2minutes($duration[$idx][$chan]);

                $bill_print = seconds2minutes($val);
                if($number_calls[$idx][$chan] > 0) {
                    $percent_missed = $missed[$idx][$chan] * 100 / $number_calls[$idx][$chan];
                } else {
                    $percent_missed = 0;
                }
                $percent_missed = number_format($percent_missed,0)." "._('%');

                $complete_self = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                //$complete_self .= "&chan=$chan&startd=$start&endd=$end&direction=$typerecord";
                echo "<tr $odd>\n";


                echo "<td style='text-align: left;'><a onclick=\"javascript:getRecords('$chan','$start','$end','$typerecord','$complete_self');\">";
                echo "<img src='images/asternic_loading.gif' id='loading$chan' border=0 style=\"visibility: hidden; float: left;\">";
                echo "{$canals[$chan]}</a></td>\n";


                echo "<td>".$number_calls[$idx][$chan]."</td>\n";
                echo "<td>".$nomissed."</td>\n";
                echo "<td>".$missed[$idx][$chan]."</td>\n";
                echo "<td align=right>".$percent_missed."</td>\n";
                echo "<td>$bill_print</td>\n";
                $percentage_bill = $val * 100 / $total_bill;
                $percentage_bill = number_format($percentage_bill,2);
                echo "<td>$percentage_bill "._('%')."</td>\n";
                echo "<td>$avg_duration_print</td>\n";
                echo "<td>$ring_time "._('secs')."</td>\n";
                echo "<td>$avg_ring_time "._('secs')."</td>\n";
                echo "</tr>\n";
                echo "<tr style='display: none;' id='$chan'><td colspan=10>";
                echo "<span id='table${chan}table'></span>\n";
                echo "</td></tr>";

                $linea_pdf = Array(
                                     $canals[$chan],
                                     $number_calls[$idx][$chan],
                                     $missed[$idx][$chan],
                                     $percent_missed,
                                     "$bill_print ",
                                     "$percentage_bill "._('%'),
                                     "$avg_duration_print ",
                                     "$ring_time "._('secs'),
                                     "$avg_ring_time "._('secs')
                );
                $data_pdf[]=$linea_pdf;
                $contador++;

           }
           //$query1.="title=".$rep_title."$graphcolor";
           $query1.="title="._($rep_title)."$graphcolorstack&tagA="._('Completed')."&tagB="._('Missed');
           $query2.="title="._('Total Call Duration by User')."$graphcolor";
           $query3.="title="._('Incoming/Outgoing Calls by User')."$graphcolorstack&tagA=$tagA&tagB=$tagB";

    }
    echo "</tbody>\n";
    echo "</table>\n";

    $cover_pdf = _('Report Information')."\n";
    $cover_pdf.= _('Start Date').": ".$start_parts[0]."\n";
    $cover_pdf.= _('End Date').": ".$end_parts[0]."\n";
    $cover_pdf.= _('Period').": ".$period." "._('days')."\n\n";
    $cover_pdf.= $rep_title."\n";
    $cover_pdf.= _('Number of Calls').": ".$total_calls." "._('calls')."\n";
    $cover_pdf.= _('Total Time').": ".$total_bill_print." "._('mins')."\n";
    $cover_pdf.= _('Avg. ring time').": ".$avg_ring_full." "._('secs')."\n";

    print_exports($header_pdf,$data_pdf,$width_pdf,$title_pdf,$cover_pdf);

    echo "<table class='pepa' width='99%' cellpadding=3 cellspacing=3 border=0>\n";
    echo "<thead>\n";
    echo "<tr><td><hr/></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td align=center bgcolor='#fffdf3' width='100%'>\n";
    swf_bar($query1,718,433,"chart1",1);
    echo "</td></tr><tr><td><hr/></td></tr>\n";
    echo "<tr><td align=center bgcolor='#fffdf3' width='100%'>\n";
    swf_bar($query2,718,433,"chart2",0);
    echo "</td></tr><tr><td><hr/></td></tr>\n";
    echo "<tr><td align=center bgcolor='#fffdf3' width='100%'>\n";
    swf_bar($query3,718,433,"chart3",1);
    echo "</td></tr>\n";
    echo "</thead>\n";
    echo "</table><BR>\n";


} // end if totalbill > 1


?>
```

solo es parte del codigo ya que es mkuy largo y la razon es que no puedo actualizarlo porque si se actualiza un componente se hecha a perder todo el codigo que esta construido

este es el boton el cual me manda al formulario de exportar excel/csv o pdf

```
 $complete_self = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    //echo "<br/><form method=post action='modules/asternic_cdr/export.php'>\n";
echo "<br/><form method='get' action='$complete_self'>\n";
    foreach($_REQUEST as $kkey=>$vval) {
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='$kkey' value='".$vval."' />\n";
    }
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='export' />\n";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='head' value='".$head_serial."' />\n";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='rawdata' value='".$data_serial."' />\n";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='width' value='".$width_serial."' />\n";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='title' value='".$title_serial."' />\n";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='cover' value='".$cover_serial."' />\n";
    echo "<a href='javascript:void()' class='info'><input type=image name='pdf' src='images/asternic_pdf.gif' style='border:0;'><span>";
            echo _('Export to PDF');
    echo "</span></a>\n";
    echo "<a href='javascript:void()' class='info'><input type=image name='csv' src='images/asternic_excel.gif' style='border:0;'><span>"; 
            echo _('Export to CSV/Excel');
    echo "</span></a>\n";
    echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Exactamente de todo eso... cual es la parte que "no entiendes bien"?

Comment: Por lo que entiendo quieres agregar una columna con datos a un código que ya esta estable, imprime antes los parámetros de tu función ```print_exports```, porque parece que ahi mandan los encabezados, datos y otros parametros, si es asi, tan solo podrías añadir a esas variables los nuevos datos

Comment: trato de guardar en csv la columna completed

Comment: en tu variable ```$header_pdf```, añade el nombre de tu columna, en el orden que quieres que aparezca, y tu variable ```$data_pdf``` se esta creando como array de datos en el foreach, ahi tendrias que calcular antes el array de valores con los que se llenara esa columna e irlos iterando con el alias del foreach ```$chan```

Comment: es aqui no -->
function print_exports($header_pdf,$data_pdf,$width_pdf,$title_pdf,$cover_pdf) {
 global $lang;
 global $language;
 $head_serial = serialize($header_pdf);
 $data_serial = serialize($data_pdf);
 $width_serial = serialize($width_pdf);
 $title_serial = serialize($title_pdf);
 $cover_serial = serialize($cover_pdf);
 $head_serial = rawurlencode($head_serial);
 $data_serial = rawurlencode($data_serial);
 $width_serial = rawurlencode($width_serial);
 $title_serial = rawurlencode($title_serial);
 $cover_serial = rawurlencode($cover_serial);